# Problems reverting a zlib compression made through compress2(), in React Native

Tags: react-native, qt, zlib

I have a binary file that was compressed in QT, using the compress2() from zlib, as seen in the following source code.

```
QByteArray qCompress(const uchar* data, int nbytes, int compressionLevel)
{
    if (nbytes == 0) {
        return QByteArray(4, '\0');
    }
    if (!data) {
        qWarning("qCompress: Data is null");
        return QByteArray();
    }
    if (compressionLevel < -1 || compressionLevel > 9)
        compressionLevel = -1;
    ulong len = nbytes + nbytes / 100 + 13;
    QByteArray bazip;
    int res;
    do {
        bazip.resize(len + 4);
        res = ::compress2((uchar*)bazip.data()+4, &len, data, nbytes, compressionLevel);
        switch (res) {
        case Z_OK:
            bazip.resize(len + 4);
            bazip[0] = (nbytes & 0xff000000) >> 24;
            bazip[1] = (nbytes & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
            bazip[2] = (nbytes & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
            bazip[3] = (nbytes & 0x000000ff);
            break;
        case Z_MEM_ERROR:
            qWarning("qCompress: Z_MEM_ERROR: Not enough memory");
            bazip.resize(0);
            break;
        case Z_BUF_ERROR:
            len *= 2;
            break;
        }
    } while (res == Z_BUF_ERROR);
    return bazip;
}
```

Now, I need to decompress it in my React Native application. For that I am using the 'react-zlib-js' and trying the inflate() method.

```
const zlib = require("react-zlib-js");
import { writeFile, readFile } from "react-native-fs";

async function decompressBinaryDatabaseFile() {
    try {
      const buffer = await readFile(fullBinaryFileName, "base64");

      await zlib.inflate(buffer, { raw: true }, (err: any, result: string) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error decompressing database file: ", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Decompressed database file: ", result);
          writeFile(fullDatabaseFileName, result, "base64")
            .then((success) => {
              console.log("FILE WRITTEN!");
              openDatabase();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err.message);
            });
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error decompressing database file: ", error);
    }
  }
```

When calling the function above I get "Error: incorrect header check". I've also tried other method from the zlib page, such as inflateSync, inflateRaw, gunzip and others. I have also tried slicing the buffer, to remove the first 4 bytes of the array, but the result is the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I now tried decompressing the same file in nodejs and it worked perfectly, so I know for sure the file is fine.

```
const zlib = require('node:zlib');
const fs = require('node:fs');
const file = "./4826dd1c8821d8e08030a80ed0c12ef9";

var data = fs.readFileSync(file, "hex");

data = data.slice(4);

zlib.inflate(data, function(err, buffer) {
    if (err) throw err;

    fs.writeFileSync("output.db", buffer);
      
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{ raw: true }`. You have a zlib stream, not a raw stream.

The first four bytes of what is written by `qCompress()` is the uncompressed length in big-endian order. What follows is a zlib stream. Indeed, you need to start decompressing four bytes in.

The result of `qCompress()` is binary data. That is what needs to be fed to `zlib.inflate()` (after the first four bytes). However I see the option "base64", whereas there is no Base-64 encoding in `qCompress()`. What *exactly* are you feeding to `zlib.inflate()`? Can you provide the first 30 or so bytes of that in hexadecimal?

Comment: I was just trying all kinds of option settings and forgot that one there. Without that raw tag also just doesn't seem to work, neither with {level: 9} (which was the original level used), nor without any options.

Comment: `{level: 9}` is only relevant for compression. Decompression doesn't care about what level it was compressed at.

Comment: I see. May I ask you which options would you consider trying?

Comment: You need to answer the questions in my answer.

Comment: As for the base64 part, the library I'm using (react-native-fs) suggests using that encoding for opening binary files. If I try the default (utf8) I get "Invalid UTF-8 detected".

As for the binary file as hex, here are the few initial bytes:

00 5e a0 00 78 da ec bd 07 78 13 c7 d6 f0 af 55 
ef 8b 69 c6 54 11 a2 01 02 36 92 dc 4d 5d c9 6b
23 b0 25 23 c9 a6 84 c4 21 b4 10 48 e8 81 84 2

I tried using the hexadecimal value of the buffer as you mentioned, also without the first four bytes, and now I'm getting "Error: unknown compression method".

Comment: Good. The binary data is correct, with a valid zlib stream beginning with the `78 da`.

Comment: The statement in the documentation "Use base64 for reading binary files" only makes sense if the data was encoded in Base-64 in the first place. Try the "ascii" encoding.

Comment: Trying both base64 and ascii to compare the results:

First bytes ASCII:  005ea00078daecbd
Last bytes ASCII:  be59ff0fc6166415
First bytes base64:  005ea00078daecbd
Last bytes base64:  be59ff0fc6166415

Comment: Ok, then "base64" decoding doesn't mean Base-64 decoding. In any case, if you are feeding `inflate` the _binary_ data represented in hexadecimal as `78 da ec bd 07 78 13 c7 d6 ...`, then the decompression will work. (You haven't provided the entire zlib stream, but I am presuming that it is correct.)

Comment: Maybe this library just doesn't work then... Thanks for the help anyways.

Comment: It is far, far, far more probable that you are doing something wrong than that the library doesn't work.

Comment: I'm referring to the React Native one... I am able to decompress the same file in a pure nodejs environment.